# How can I set up a policy on Windows XP to logout all users at midnight?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, logout

Sometimes the kids are on the computer too late and rather than yelling at them I want the computer to help me out. I already have a separate user set up so they don't have admin access to the computer but I can't find how I can force only certain login times.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider marking an accepted answer. If you need further help, please post a comment or edit your question to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Create a scheduled task. Go to the control panel and find "Scheduled Tasks", then create a task to run at midnight. You have several options for the action it should take:

- Just log off - no warning: `shutdown.exe -l`
- Force shutdown, but give warning: `shutdown.exe -s -t SECONDS_TO_WAIT -c "Bedtime!"`
- Force shutdown, no warning: `shutdown.exe -s -t 0`

If you also want to prevent them from logging back on, you can use the `NET USER` command line tool to specify their permitted logon hours. In Windows 7 you can do this through Parental Controls GUI, but on Windows XP you need to do it from the command line. For more info, see the [Microsoft documentation for net user](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_user.mspx?mfr=true), specifically the `/times` switch.

Comment: Also, just a note... I don't know how old your kids are, but keep in mind that there may be times when they'll need the computer for extended hours for homework. When I was in high school I would often have lab reports, etc. which would have be researching/processing data/typing reports until well after midnight. Just something to keep in mind - the technical solution could end up being a problem for them at times, so just make sure to discuss it with them if that might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I'm not a big advocate of putting restrictions on computers but sometimes it's easier than arguing about it. I'll make sure whatever I do I can override if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is completely what you want, but [K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) is a child's (or children's) web filtering and blocking software that is *extremely* configurable.  You could turn off all the settings that you didn't want (filtering, word block, site block, category block), and **just use the Internet time feature.**  *You can set what hours of the day you want the Internet on the computer to be blocked, and can customize each day of the week.*  All settings are accessed via the web browser, and are protected by a password, which you could give to someone else and not know yourself if you wanted to completely block access.  It works cross-browsers; one configuration covers Internet Explorer, Firefox, and others all one the same machine.

K9 Web Protection: http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

Did I mention that it is FREE?

Comment: Sweet!  I'll have to check that out before I set up login time restrictions. But generally I'm not a big fan of having to install more software (even if it's free!).